# Why am i getting javascript and html code when using ajax to send and return value from php?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

Today I tried Ajax with the below code. Logic seems to be correct because success function is triggering but i can't able to get return value from php file, instead i'm getting Javascript and html code when i alert the response.

example1.php

```
 <?php
    echo $_POST['name'];
 ?>
<form action="?" method="post">
<input type="text" id="d1" name="name" value="">
<input type="text" id="d2" name="place" value="">
<input id="target" type="submit" name="submit" value="send">
</form> 
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#target").click(function()
{
var data1=$("#d1").val();
var data2=$("#d2").val();
$.ajax
({
type:"POST",
url:"example1.php",
data:{name:data1,place:data2},
success:function(msg)
{
alert(msg);
}
});
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

When i run the example1.php it shows the alert message like given below
    Submitted name

```
<form action="?" method="post">
<input type="text" id="d1" name="name" value="">
<input type="text" id="d2" name="place" value="">
<input id="target" type="submit" name="submit" value="send">
</form> 
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#target").click(function()
{
var data1=$("#d1").val();
var data2=$("#d2").val();
$.ajax
({
type:"POST",
url:"arithmetic.php",
data:{name:data1,place:data2},
success:function(msg)
{
alert(msg);
}
});
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Why am i getting this instead of name and place value from example1.php?

Comment: Why did you edit your question with `<form action="?"`? The operative character being >> **?** << - you should explain the "why".

Comment: After your edit, the question became confusing... How many php files you're talking about now? And what "name and place value from example1.php"? You removed all php code... Could you please clarify?

Comment: @bfavaretto only one file. now i added php code in it. i can get value but along with the client side whole code

Comment: @Fred i used ? to submit value to the same page

Comment: @bfavaretto thanks for your extra bit of information to use submit function. it is helpful

Comment: @raj Save yourself the extra keystroke and just use `action=""`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE considering that the question changed**

You're posting to the same file where the form is, so your response includes the HTML code in that page. You have to post to a different PHP file that only responds with the content you want, or change your current file to respond differently if some data was posted.

---

Your ajax request is not going to `response.php`, because you told jQuery to post to a different URL:

```
url:"arithmetic.php",
```

Change that to response.php.

---

To guarantee you always post with ajax, you should bind to the form's `submit` event, instead of the submit button click:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {

    // ajax stuff

    // prevent default (submit)
    return false;
});
```

With your current code, the form will submit without ajax if you hit enter while focused on one of those input fields.

Comment: Seems right, although it doesn't explain why the alert is showing the entire contents of the `example1.php` page.

Comment: I for one am curious. Does the action still need to be `<form action="response.php" method="post">` or can that be left blank, since it's inside the Ajax?

Comment: @Barmar I guess example1.php was just an example, and in the actual code it's arithmetic.php

Comment: agree with this answer, just want to add a little improvement. Instead write response code as follows <?php
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {echo $_POST['name'];
echo $_POST['place']; exit(0); }
?>

Comment: @Fred Yes, if you leave it blank it will assume it should post to the current page. You should take an extra precaution to guarantee you always post with ajax, I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Fred It can be left out, which just means it defaults to `action=""`, i.e. the action is the current page.

Comment: @Barmar That's what I thought. I thought that it made a difference if using Ajax. I'm just getting my head into Ajax myself, and having a bit of a hard time right now, but I'll get the hang of it.

Comment: @Fred It's not AJAX per se that's the issue, it's the fact that you have a `click` handler that's processing the submit button. It returns `false` to prevent the default submission. So the action is ignored.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the extra bit of information, it's well noted.

Comment: @bfavaretto Thanks. Sorry i tried when i was getting alert with one file alone i,e one php alone.so tried to send to another file weather am getting same bug or not that is why i left that mistake without my knowledge.Now see my edits

Comment: @bfavaretto considering your answer i tried that in different file earlier(before posting question) but in that i left that arithmetic.php without my knowledge so i posted that question.before i was 90% only sure about the bug now from your answer i am 100% sure about it.thanks for your answer:)

Comment: @bfavaretto can we specifically get only certain value from php file?

Comment: @raj You can echo conditionally, e.g., `if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['place'])) { /* POST detected, echo your variables */ } else { /* echo your HTML */ }`

Comment: @bfavaretto i tried to hit enter while filling form even though its displaying the variable in ajax function i,e alerting the value

Answer (score 0):

chage the url to
`url:"response.php"`

and write the code in responce.php like this

```
$name=$_POST["name"];
$place=$_POST["place"];
```

Comment: You mean like bfavaretto's answer over 10 minutes ago?

Comment: @bfavaretto Seems like the **"plot thickens"**, *"as it were"*.

Answer (score 0):

Change your response code as follows. You need to stop execution after writing your response.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
echo $_POST['name']; 
echo $_POST['place']; 
exit(0); 
} 
?>
```